# Taking average of user input number

Tags: java

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class eCheck10A
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  PrintStream out = System.out;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  out.print("Enter your integers");
  out.println("Negative = sentinel");

  List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();



  for (int n1 = in.nextInt(); n1 > 0; n1 = in.nextInt())
  {
          if(n1 < 0)
          {
          break;
          }
  }


 }
}
```

if i want to take all the numbers that I enter for n1, and average them out, how do i refer to all these numbers? I am going to put them in the IF statement, so if a negative number is entered, the program stops and posts their average.

Comment: If you know what averages are, it is a sum of all "items" divided by the number of those "items". So.... I guess the first thing you need is a sum of all the `n1`'s and keep a count of how many of them there are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pseudocode you need to do this task (pseudo-code since it looks suspiciously like homework/classwork and you'll become a better developer if you nut out the implementation yourself).

Because you don't need the numbers themselves to work out the average, there's no point in storing them. The average is defined as the sum of all numbers divided by their count, so that's all you need to remember. Something like this should suffice:

```
total = 0
count = 0
n1 = get_next_number()
while n1 >= 0:
    total = total + n1
    count = count + 1
    n1 = get_next_number()
if count == 0:
    print "No numbers were entered.
else:
    print "Average is ", (total / count)
```

---

A couple of other points I'll mention. As it stands now, your `for` statement will exit at the first non-positive number (`<= 0`), making the `if` superfluous.

In addition, you probably *want* any zeros to be included in the average: the average of `{1,2,3} = 2` is not the same as the average of `{1,2,3,0,0,0} = 1`.

You can do this in the `for` statement itself with something like:

```
for (int n1 = in.nextInt(); n1 >= 0; n1 = in.nextInt())
```

and then you don't need the `if/break` bit inside the loop at all, similar to my provided pseudo-code.

Comment: one question, "while n1 = get_next_number():", we cant do that cause equal sign requires a boolean

Comment: It's pseudocode, @user1519192, it can mean whatever you want :-) However, I'll clarify to make it closer to Java. In any case, you can stick with the `for` variant as per the latter part of this answer.

Comment: but this isnt right tho, it outputs the last two numbers the user enters. for example, if you enter {4,5,3}, it outputs 4. plus when i enter a negative number, i want the program to stop asking me to enter another number

Comment: @user1519192: the average of `{4,5,3}` is _indeed_ 4, there's no problem in that. And entering a negative number will cause `n1 >= 0` to be false, hence exiting the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

An outline of what you will need to do: Create a variable sum to add up all of the values and create another variable called count that will be used to store the number of non-negative numbers in your list, aList. Then divide the sum by the count to find the average.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do running average is:
new_average = old_average + (new_number - old_average ) / count 
If you ever hit max for a variable type, you would appreciate this formula.