# stopping a loop in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Taking average of user input number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732171/taking-average-of-user-input-number)

```
for (int n1 = in.nextInt(); n1 >= 0; n1 = in.nextInt())
  {
          int total = 0;
          int count = 0;

          while (n1 >= 0)
          {
                  n1 = in.nextInt();
                  total = total + n1;
                  count = count + 1;

          }
          out.println(total);
          out.println(count);
  }
```

i want all the numbers that I enter to be added up, is this code correct? It only adds my last 2 inputs. I want the loop keep going until the user enters a negative number, then then loop stops and then it outputs my total and count.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Printstream out = System.out;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why can't you do it in a single `while` loop?

Comment: heh, so the previous [pseudocode to outline this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11732204/851273) wasn't good enough?

Comment: It looks like a assignment-like question, the above link from Jon Lin should do. Please try to implement by the pseudocode mentioned in the above link

Answer (score 2):

```
int total = 0;
int count = 0;

while (true) {
    int n = in.nextInt();
    if (n < 0) 
        break;
    total += n;
    count ++;
}
out.println(total);
out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as follows.

```
int total = 0;
int count = 0;
int n1;

try
{
    while((n1=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()))>=0)
    {
        total = total + n1;
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}

out.println("Total     = "+total);
out.println("Count     = "+count);

Format df=new DecimalFormat("#.##");
out.println("Average   = "+df.format((double)total/count));
```